# how to write where clause with rawquery

Tags: sqlite

> Hi, I have some problem to fetch data from sqlite database. Here i am fetching 
>   data from select query but it is not responding. Please help me.

```
public ArrayList<String> getStudentsByClass(String stud_info) {
    // Log.i("SKR", "GETTING STUDENTS by " +stud_class);

        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = liteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE2  +
            " WHERE ssg ='" + stud_info + "'", null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                arrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_STUDENT_NAME)));

                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
    }
    return arrayList;
}
```

Comment: Does it work to run the intended SQL query directly from command line tool? I.e. without interference by the language you did not tag.

Comment: Please provide the `.dump`of  a suitably tailiored toy database, as a [mcve]. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: sir, if i fetch data without where clause i.e. SELECT * FROM stud_data; then it works properly

Comment: Good for you. But if you want my help with your question, i.e. with what does not work, then please try some of the things I proposed. Tagging your language is the way to attract more help, other than mine.

Comment: You do have access to the SQLite command line tool and know how to use it on your database, don't you?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "not responding"? Does your app hang?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a raw query from a DBHelper Class that when called populates an ArrayList

```
    /* Retrive ALL data from database table named "TABLE_INFO" */
public List<DatabaseModel> getDataFromDB(){
    List<DatabaseModel> modelList = new ArrayList<>();

    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_INFO;
    //String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_INFO + " WHERE " + Col_ID + " > 0 " + " ORDER BY " + Col_ID + " DESC ";
    /* Notice the SPACES before AND after the words WHERE ORDER BY ASC or DESC most of all the condition " > 0 "*/
    /* =+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=*/
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            DatabaseModel model = new DatabaseModel();
            model.setID(cursor.getString(0));
            model.setWebsite(cursor.getString(1));
            model.setUsernane(cursor.getString(2));
            model.setPassword(cursor.getString(3));
            model.setQuestion(cursor.getString(4));
            model.setAnswer(cursor.getString(5));
            model.setNotes(cursor.getString(6));

            modelList.add(model);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return modelList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using rawQuery You may include ?s in where clause in the query, which will be replaced by the values from selectionArgs. The values will be bound as Strings.

```
    String selectQuery = "select * FROM settings where _id = ?";
    String args[] = {"1"};

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, args);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
```